# Execute a samba mount command without password prompt from PHP?

Tags: php, samba, cifs

I want to write a script in PHP that executes a samba mount temporary by command

```
sudo mount -t cifs //xx.yy.zz/windows_shared /var/www/html/test -o user=TestUserWindow,uid=testuser,gid=testgroup
```

As you know it will prompt for a password **of WINDOWS** not linux.

But I want to run the script silently using `shell_exec()`.
How can I pass the password automatically without prompt?

Comment: Add in /etc/sudoers

Comment: Sorry I just missing some important part in my question. I mean password of Windows account for file sharing, not Linux itself

Answer (score 1):

You can add user, password, and domain to your mount command. For example just having usernam and password defined yor command would look like this:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //xx.yy.zz/windows_shared /var/www/html/test -o user=TestUserWindow,password=TestUserPassword,uid=testuser,gid=testgroup
```

A better/ more secure option is to use a credential file, but you loose the option to pass a username of password from php into the mount command. Either way here is an credential file example:

1 Create credential file:

```
sudo vim /etc/php.cred
```

2 Add the username, password, and domain if need be. Make sure they are on their own line and there cannot be any spaces between either side of the equal sign:

```
username=TestUserWindow
password=TestUserPassword
domain=TestDomain
```

3 Reference the newly created credentials file in your mount command:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //xx.yy.zz/windows_shared /var/www/html/test -o credentials=/etc/php.cred,uid=testuser,gid=testgroup
```

References:

[mount](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount.cifs) cifs man page

There are also many other answers to this question. I would recommend asking "[mount cifs example using credentials file](https://serverfault.com/questions/367934/how-do-i-pass-credential-file-to-mount-cifs)" or "[mount cifs example username password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/101029/how-do-i-mount-a-cifs-share)". Basically drop the "php" part of your question as you are executing a shell command and not in php anymore.